# Loading a HTML5 video to use with canvas

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

Good day,

I need a javascript only solution to programmatically load a video, so that I can later reference it and draw it on my canvas application. I'm utterly confused on how one would check to see if a video loading is complete, since there is no event for that. Also, it seems, that video.load() doesn't load anything, and I can't seem to get any attributes (everything comes up as null) of the video element, even after starting it to play with video.play().

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: searching google for `html5 video canvas` returns quite a few examples, like this one.. http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: @Ben — It has nothing to do with actually loading the video. The video is being put in by HTML markup. I explicitly said i need a javascript only solution to actually _manage loading and tracking progress_ of a video object, not manipulating it.

Comment: Your question title is confusing then.. anyway, is the the [loadedmetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension) event you're looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html5: display video inside canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

A cross-browser implementation of a progress-event can be found in the jMediaelement-libary.

https://github.com/aFarkas/jMediaelement

Answer (score 0):

Could [Video.js](http://videojs.com/docs/api/) be what you are looking for? It provides an API which allows access to to tracking and setting of progress.

Answer (score 0):

http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/ can help i guess