# How to play a cutscene in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am wondering if it is possible to play a video file from within a HTML5 Canvas without the video player settings cropping up.

For example, something like this:

```
ctx.playMovie("movie.mov")
```

I know it is possible to put a video player in the canvas, but I plan to make a cutscene player for my game. Is there a way to play a video file automatically once, or do I have to manually upload every frame of the sequence?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make it appear automatically instead of having to play the video first?

Comment: Yes, add attribute `autoplay` to the video tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/on1kh4o0/439/