# prevent video on loop cause browser ran out of memory

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

i use html5 to create a video to loop and draw the video to canvas, i create multiple canvas and draw every part of video on each canvas, but i found out after some time, it will cause google chrome ran out of memory.

here is the code to draw video on canvas.

```
v.addEventListener('play', function(){
      cw = v.clientWidth * convas_rate_width;
      ch = v.clientHeight * convas_rate_height;
      canvas.width = (videoWidth/matrix_x) * canvas_location_x;
      canvas.height = (videoHeight/matrix_y) * canvas_location_y;
      back.width = cw;
      back.height = ch;


      draw(v,context,context,cw,ch,x,y,matrix_x, matrix_y);
    },false);

function draw(v,c,bc,w,h,x,y,matrix_x,matrix_y) {
    if(v.paused || v.ended) return false;
    // First, draw it into the backing canvas

    var x_coord = -((w/matrix_x) * x);
    var y_coord = -((h/matrix_y) * y);

    bc.drawImage(v,x_coord,y_coord,w,h);
    // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
    var idata = bc.getImageData(0,0,(w),(h));


    var data = idata.data;
    // Loop through the pixels, turning them grayscale

    idata.data = data;
    // Draw the pixels onto the visible canvas
    c.putImageData(idata,0,0);
    // Start over!
    setTimeout(draw,10,v,c,bc,w,h,x,y,matrix_x, matrix_y);
  }
```

Here is the printscreen : [**Google Chrome ran out of memory**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QBuh.jpg)

[image]

Is there anyway to prevent looped video causing the "out of memory" error?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of missing code so can not say where the memory is being used. Most likely you are either closing over the image data thus keeping a reference and not letting the browser delete it or you specifically make a copy of the reference, effectively doing the same thing.

Also you should not use setTimeout to show video frames. Use `requestAnimationFrame`

To convert to grey you dont need to get the image data you can use the composite operation to do that.

- [Displaying video in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38711016/3877726) shows how to display a video in the canvas.
- [Canvas filters for realtime video FX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39026987/3877726) show how to get a variety of video FX (including Black and White) using the built in canvas `globalCompositeOperation` which is significantly quicker and uses much less memory than manually processing pixels in javascript via the `imageData` array.