# how to capture html5 video programmatically (headless)

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, video-capture, xvfb

I am trying to capture html5 video with js/css effects on it programmatically. I tried a couple of methods;

1. First I find this great [blog post](https://mindthecode.com/recording-a-website-with-phantomjs-and-ffmpeg/) and implemented it. Everything was perfect till I found that phantomjs [is not supporting](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10839) html5 video tag so can not capture the video.
2. Second option was to use headless chrome to take continuous [screenshots](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and feed these screenshots into ffmpeg to create the video. Although it worked to some level headless chromes screenshots was taking some time.. I couldn't create a smooth video..
3. On my third try I gave a chance to chrome's Page.startScreencast api. It could get video capture but frame rates was really problematic. The reason is [that](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/17#issuecomment-303621717)..
4. Now I am working on xvfb + chrome/firefox + ffmpeg combination for capturing video as mentioned on [that](https://github.com/adieuadieu/serverless-chrome/issues/17#issuecomment-313425331) comment. Theoretically it is promising but I couldn't managed to capture a video. Instead I have black screen..

My setup is below:

- light-http server having a simple video (web) within html5 video tag; on localhost
- start xvfb with Firefox and navigate to localhost/index.html ( video is there ) 

  `xvfb-run --listen-tcp --server-num 44 --auth-file /tmp/xvfb.auth -s "-ac -screen 0 1440x685x24" firefox --headless http://localhost`
- start ffmpeg with x11grab parameter to grab frames from xvfb

  `ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1440x685 -i :44 -codec:v libx264 -r 12 ./output.mp4`
- the result is black video :)

what should be the problem, how can I debug the problem?

---

ps: there is one more possible solution which I didn't tried yet. As phantomjs has capability to capture canvas; it may be possible to

- put [video into canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas)
- then capture the canvas

It seems like a dirty workaround that is why not tried yet..

---

UPDATE-1

Tried to get screenshot with `xwd -root -silent -display :44 -out screen.xwd`and than convert to jpeg `convert screen.xwd shot.jpg` the result is black jpg..

Comment: Try adding `-vf format=yuv420p` (or `-pix_fmt yuv420p` alias) and `-movflags +faststart` output options in your ffmpeg command. Remove `-r 12` and replace it with `-framerate 12` input option. Use a width and height that is divisible by 2:
`ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1440x684 -framerate 12 -i :44 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart ./output.mp4`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I did it but again I have black screen.. may it be related to xvfb-run ? how can I check that ffmpeg has right sources of frames ?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is not `ffmpeg` related. I've never used xvfb so I can't comment on that. As for checking the right source of frames, just check that you have the proper input  `:display_number.screen_number` and view the output, as you did.

Comment: Are you sure your video is not encrypted? If it is then the device will actively try to stop you doing this and you common will end up with a black screen, frame or image on many devices.

Comment: @Mick I download video from youtube for test purposes, it is not encrypted, actually I can view video from localhost/index.html when opened it from a normal browser..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the "live video output" I would suggest capturing video frame by frame. Here is the speech about some existing application https://vimeo.com/342829825

Otherwise, if life stream is required, you may go with the way that [obs-linuxbrowser](https://github.com/bazukas/obs-linuxbrowser) is doing. So [cef](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) + ffmpeg.