# imageData on paletted png results in nearly duplicate colors

Tags: javascript, canvas, imagedata

It's as it sounds.

[image]

The three brownish colors in the lower left corner above.

[image]

I expect up to 60 different colors from a paletted png with a palette that contains 60 colors on an image that claims only 16 colors, which I translated to the desired palette, then made sure the image was paletted.

When I go to fetch the palette back from the canvas things are not as they seem.

I really, really don't want to fight against whatever is going on in order to eliminate these *near duplicates*.

Is there a no-brainer solution, or is it simply "not a chance", good luck with the math for whatever reasons?

EDIT:
Current code attempt is here:
https://editor.p5js.org/CodeSoup2022/sketches/sbiKb8rqc

The colors in the `userPalette` of the sketch are as reported by gimp. There are 26 of them in `0xRRGGBB`.

The image file is included with the sketch.

Comment: fwiw, I tried using an imagebitmap with premultifiedAlpha set to none, but no joy. The canvas likes to render things quickly which is good almost all the time, but it's also dorking the original image data by the time we're able to access it.

Comment: looks like `ImageBitmap.getImageData()` would solve it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107674/1321944

Comment: Please share exactly what you are doing, with code. It's relatively unclear currently. If you can also share an example png file that would help a lot.

Comment: Also there doesn't seem to be any alpha in your pallette, right? If so, you're not concerned by alpha premultiplication.

Comment: Correct, alpha isn't necessary. Honestly, I could easily go with pngjs, but ugh...

Comment: Your image is nothing like the original one at https://opengameart.org/content/metroid-like The colors have been messed up by Gimp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254207/discussion-between-nolo-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, gimp wasn't fudging anything.

I can't explain why exactly the canvas produces slightly varied color values, but it's at least helpful to know that it does.

I.E. doing:

```
ctx.drawImage ( htmlImgageElement, x, y )
ctx.getImageData ( 0, 0, width, height )
```

is half baked in one way or another.

When I load the image using https://github.com/pngjs/pngjs/:

```
fetch ( 'metroid-like.png' )
  .then ( response => response.arrayBuffer () )
  .then ( buffer => {
    new png.PNG ( { filterType: 4 } )
      .parse ( buffer, function ( error, data ) {
        // handle raw data
      } )
  } )
```

I see the expected 26 color values that gimp reports and each of the apparently blank background tiles gets hashed properly and deduplicated in the resulting tile set.

For reference, the full code is here:
https://editor.p5js.org/CodeSoup2022/sketches/sbiKb8rqc