# HTML - Image hover swap to short video

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to a list of images and when the user hover one of the images it swaps to short video.
Exactly like Youtube. When I hover my mouse over an image, it changes to a short video, and when I move the mouse it stops and return to image.

How can I achive such thing? What should I use? Can I achive that with Javascript?
Maybe there is library or package in the open source that I can use?

I'm lost and I have been searching alot.

Comment: use a js canvas and some mouse listener

Comment: can you give some of codes that you've been tried so far

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas

Comment: @Gad i'm sorry but i did not write any code. I have no clue with that to start. Well I have only image and thats it. Didn't write any Javascript code or something else

Comment: @ChristopheChenel Thanks for you answer, but thats not what I'm looking for. What I'm trying to do is like Youtube. When you hover your mouse over an image it changes the image to a video.

Comment: yeah well, now you know how to put a video in a canvas. Just code the mouse hover logic and it's done.

Comment: @ChristopheChenel Yeah, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put each image inside a div. In each div add an `onmouseenter` and `onmouseout` attribute. The id will be used later. These attributes "listen" for when the user's mouse enters or leaves the div element:

```
<div id = "0" onmouseenter = "makeVideo(this)" onmouseout = "makeImage(this)">
<img>
</div>
```

We then need to define the `makeVideo` and `makeImage` functions:

```
<script>
   pairs = [["<img src = 'example.png'>","<video autoplay><source src='example.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>"]] // create an array where each element pairs an image element string with a video. You will need a sub-array for each image and video pair

makeVideo = function(element){ //take the div as an input
   element.innerHTML = pairs[element.id][1] // take the appropriate video string based on the div id, and put it inside the div
}

makeImage = function(element){ 
   element.innerHTML = pairs[element.id][0] // this time use the img
}
</script>
```

Then just scale up to however many images you need.
Some things to keep in mind:
Make sure you set the `width` and `height` attributes of your videos to be the same.
Remember to give each div an id corresponding to its index in the `pairs` array
The most time-consuming part if you choose to use this method will probably be creating the `pairs` array with all the html strings.
Hope you get this working!

Comment: Also remember to give each video the autoplay attribute, as shown in the example