# How to open a link in a HTML canvas tag?

Tags: html, canvas, hyperlink

I have an issue: I would like to open the content of a link( the content is a recording of a security camera) inside an HTML canvas tag, is that possible if yes can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429862/6231562) maybe solve your scope as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean open the link as in open the security camera footage and have it display inside the canvas or open a link as in be able to click on the link inside the canvas?

If you are just looking to playback video inside a canvas here is another Stack Overflow post on how to do that: [Displaying video inside HTML Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429440/html5-display-video-inside-canvas)

If your intent is to open the link and have the link's content  become the canvas I would suggest using and `<iframe>` tag instead or floating that iframe on top of the canvas. You can learn more about those here: [HTML iframe tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

If you are just trying to have a link clickable inside the canvas there are a few ways I can think of.

One method would be floating an `<a>` element on top of the canvas with absolute positioning or something similar.

The other way I can think of is creating a clickable region that encompasses the text which you want to be a link and style the text to look and respond as though it is a link.