# How add a border frame on a video webcam in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video

I'm using react-webcam library on my react project (Not react native), but I need add a border frame (png file) to record a video and download. How I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KntGy.jpg)

Comment: Possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4429862/6691714

Answer (score 0):

`react-webcam` takes a `className` as a prop, much like passing it mute, or whatever.

You could, in theory, pass a CSS style that adds a pseudo element to your video, or something similar. Is that what you're looking to do?